# Предложения являются СПП?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

1. Лешка не ужаснулся тому, что начинает привыкать к безликости той единицы.
2. Васконян умиленно радовался тому, что Бог послал ему еще одного доброго человека.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Являются. Оба предложения содержат придаточное изъяснительное. Указательное слово *тому* и союз *что* соединяют части сложного предложения.

Comment: Спасибо вам!!!!!

Comment: Если ответ исчерпывающий, примите его (надо нажать на кнопку справа от ответа).